# Macro with arguments used in a return statement

Tags: c, programming-languages, c-preprocessor

I have confusion on following c code

```
#define MACRO (xx) \
foo(xx)
...    
#ifdef A
return MACRO(a);
#endif
...
```

The source can not compile. But when I change definition to

```
#define MACRO \
foo(a)
```

So if I want to use MACRO with argument in this case, how should I do? Thanks..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the space between `MACRO` and `(xx)`.

If you leave the space there, the preprocessor doesn't treat `(xx)` as the argument, but as part of the expansion.  So whenever it sees `MACRO`, it replaces it with `(xx) foo(xx)`.

Comment: @R.. @mathk Don't I count as a "kid"?